# Multiple select question on holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a multiple select question.

Let $f$, $g$ be analytic functions defined on $A \cup D$, where

$A$ = $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: \frac{1}{2} <|z| < 1\}$

and $D$ = $\{z \in \Bbb{C}: |z-2| <1\}$

I need to choose the correct options:

$1$- If $f(z)g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in  A \cup D$, then either $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A$ or $g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A$.

$2$- If $f(z)g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in  D$, then either $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in D$ or $g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in D$.

$3$- If $f(z)g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in  A$ , then either $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A$ or $g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A$.

$4$- If $f(z)g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in  A \cup D$, then either $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A \cup D$ or $g(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A \cup D$.

If I take $f(z) = 0$ for all $z \in A$ and $1$ for all $z \in D$ and $g(z) = 1$ for all $z \in A$ and $0$ for all $z \in D$, then option $4$ will be discarded.

I am not able to make an argument for the rest of the options.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other statements are true. Take the second one, for instance. If $f(z_0)\ne0$ for some $z_0\in D$, then $f(z)\ne0$ on some neighborhood $V$ of $z_0$; by continuity. But then $(\forall z\in V):g(z)=0$. And then $g$ is the null function on $D$, by the Identity Theorem and since $D$ is connected. And now it follows that the first statement is true too.

The third one is similar.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, (1) is true as well (it is a consequence of (3)). – And I would mention that both $A$ and $D$ are *connected* whereas $A \cup D$ is not.

Comment: @MartinR Right (as usual). I misread the first statement. And I've added the reference to connectedness.

Comment: Why will $V$ have a limit point in $A \cup D$ in order to apply the identity theorem?

Comment: Because $z_0$ is a limit point of *any* of its neighborhoods.

Comment: Oh okay..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. is true. $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z \in A$ implies that either $f(z)=0$ for uncountably many $z \in A$ or $g(z)=0$ for uncountably many $z \in A$. Since zeros or isolated we see that either $f \equiv 0$ in $A$ or $g \equiv 0$ in $A$. [Uncountable sets have limit points].

The same argument shows that 2. and 3. are also true.

[Let $E=\{z: f(z) =0\}$ and $F=\{z:g(z)= 0\}$. Then $E \cup F=A$ in 1. and 3. and  $E \cup F=D$ in 2. If $E$ or $F$ has  a limit point then we are done (by Identity Theorem). If they don't have limit points then they are coutbale. So their union is counatble. This makes $A$ countbale in 1. and 3. and it makes $D$ countable in 2. This is a  contradiction].

Comment: Could you explain your statement " If $f(z)g(z)=0$ for all $z ∈ A$ implies that either $f(z) = 0$ for uncountably many $z ∈ A$ or the same for $g$

Comment: It is a simple cardinality argument. The regions are uncountable sets and union of two countable sets is countable. @Gitika

Comment: Union of two countable sets is countable. Where has it been used in your answer?

Comment: @Gitika I have added  a detailed argument.